# sql query to move values from second_names column to firstn_name column when first_name column is null

Tags: sql, database, oracle

below is my requirement

i need to push second_name values to first_name column only when first_name columns are null.

for example,

i want drake and jim to be moved to first_name column and should not be present in second_name column.Rest of the names should be same as it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
update your_table set
  first_name  = second_name,
  second_name = null
where first_name is null;
```